# white-space: nowrap not working

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I have footer with `<span>` element. In mobile screen (which I expected):

[image: mobile screen]

Desktop display (should not break into a new line) :

[image: desktop display]

My HTML and CSS:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .rwd-line {
        display: inline;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}

.rwd-line {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="text-center">
   <span class="rwd-line">&copy;<?php echo date('Y') ?> PT Paket Informasi Digital<span class="visible-lg">&bull;</span></span>
   <span class="rwd-line"><a href="https://blog.paket.id" target="_blank">Blog</a><span class="visible-lg">&bull;</span></span>
   <span class="rwd-line"><a href="https://docs.paket.id" target="_blank">Documentation</a><span class="visible-lg">&bull;</span></span>
   <span class="rwd-line"><i class="fi flaticon-phone"></i>+62 878 0878 3630</span>
</h4>
```

I have tried:

1. adding `nowrap` attribute in every `<span class="visible-lg">`
2. adding `white-space: nowrap;` in my css
3. adding `&nbsp;` entities

but none of the above resolve my problem.

P.S : I still need the `&bull` entities to be appear on desktop display

This is the result from copy and paste the jsfiddle @Hastig provided me:

[image: jsfiddle copy and paste]

Comment: Seems to work for me. What's it in your visible-lg class?

Comment: to make bullets appear on large screen @HastigZusammenstellen

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the question but try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/sbub2zrv/

Comment: Side note which doesn't answer the question: Consider changing the markup to something a little cleaner like [this example](https://jsbin.com/dogudi/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: Your jsfiddle just exactly what i am looking for. I copy and paste your code and running on my localhost, the result is just not right, take a look at my edited question @HastigZusammenstellen

Comment: I recommend inspecting each element with firefox or chrome and see if anything is being inserted inline or overridden by other css styling. ctrl+f through your stylesheet for unwanted, leftover, duplicate classes you may have left somewhere and forgot about.

Comment: yes, i already ctrl+f both my css and html file, and there is no duplicate for `visible-lg` `rwd-line` and `text-center` :(

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet post all your code to a fiddle and ile look through it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/may123/z4yrk8ca/ it looks fine in this fiddle @HastigZusammenstellen

Comment: Looks fine to me too. Without using your computer I don't think I'll be able to identify it but I had a look through your code and made a few suggestions here and there. I left comments in the html pane and the js pane. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/z4yrk8ca/4/ Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: thank you for helping me this far :) @HastigZusammenstellen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may lie with your visible-lg class, is this what you want to happen?

(view full screen and adjust width of window)

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.rwd-line {
  display: block;
}
.visible-lg {
  display: none; 
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .rwd-line {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .visible-lg {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
   <span class="rwd-line">&copy;<?php echo date('Y') ?> PT Paket Informasi Digital<span class="visible-lg">&bull;</span></span>
   <span class="rwd-line"><a href="https://blog.paket.id" target="_blank">Blog</a><span class="visible-lg">&bull;</span></span>
   <span class="rwd-line"><a href="https://docs.paket.id" target="_blank">Documentation</a><span class="visible-lg">&bull;</span></span>
   <span class="rwd-line"><i class="fi flaticon-phone"></i>+62 878 0878 3630</span>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/sbub2zrv/

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the media query last, like this:

```
.rwd-line {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .rwd-line {
        display: inline;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/xcnswLwb/**

Comment: i tried on my localhost, but it render differently with the jsfiddle you provide me, I don't know what's wrong

Comment: I just copied your code... a better way imo is to use a <ul> and set the <li> to display: inline-block for desktop. That way you have the bullet points as well :)

Comment: If you still have an issue it might be the rest of your css that's possibly overriding it. Try the inspector to see what's going on.

Comment: but how do I make the bullets appear only on large screen if I am using `<li>` tag?

Comment: you can set list-style-type for <ul>

Comment: I tried `<li>` and added `list-style-type: circle` on `@media screen and (min-width:768px)` but the circle didn't appear as I expected. I wonder if there is something wrong with my media queries?

Comment: Bullet points don't appear when <li> is set to display: inline-block. I may have misread your question. In this case just set display: inline-block to .large-visible. Is this a preset class from Bootstrap? Then it might be set automatically to display: block, so you will need to override this.

Answer (score 0):

*Change display:block; to display:inline-block; OR Try It Once .*

```
.rwd-line {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```